# Ver en el imperfecto -- stem change?

Tags: verbos

Does the verb ver have a stem change because it is conjugated mostly regularly? I mean that the stem is ve- when it would normally be v-. Just curious.

Comment: No.  *ver* historically was *veder* (*vedía*), which later became *veer* (*veía*).  Cases of *ee* eventually reduced to a single *e*, but stuck around for *veo* and *veía*

Comment: @user0721090601 that's right, don't forget verb _seer_ which became our current _[ser](https://dle.rae.es/ser)_.

Comment: @user0721090601 No Olvides «leer»

Comment: @PeterM *leer* en español nunca se redujo a *ler* (cambio que sí ocurrió en portugués y gallego).  A menos si refieres al hecho de antes ser *legere* en latin

Answer (score 2):

*Ver* comes from Latin *vidēre*, with conjugated forms like *videō* "I see" (1st person singular present tense). Latin short /i/ turned into Spanish /e/, while unstressed /eo/ usually gave /io/. So at some point this must have been *vedio* [be.ði.o], with the middle /d/ softened to [ð] (as in English *this*).

The vowels in hiatus were turned into diphthongs, so disyllabic [i.o] became monosyllabic [jo] (as in English *yo* or *yaw*); this was and is still a common tendency in Spanish.

The middle [ð] (between vowels) was lost in a lot of words in Spanish, or turned into [j] or merged with a following [j]. So we find medieval Spanish spellings like *veyo* [be.jo]. The infinitive was either *veer* or *veyer* according to dialect (the latter still exists in [Aragonese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aragonese_language)). Other tenses didn't get this [j] sound.

In time the verb was regularized and the forms with *-y-* lost it.

Finally, because the speakers' intuition said that the root was *v-* and not *ve-*, and because Spanish doesn't like vowels in hiatus (and least of all pairs of identical vowels), *veer* was simplified to *ver*. Only the imperfect retained the *ve-* root.

More or less the same happened to *ser*, which was formerly *seer*, from Latin *sedēre* "I sit, I remain". I didn't happen with *leer* because... well, just because.

Parts of this process also happened with *traer*, *caer*, *oír* and other verbs where the loss of middle consonants got two vowels in contact. You can still see the middle *-y-* in the preterite, 3rd person plural (*cayeron, oyeron*), and a different "solution" to the problem in the present, 1st person singular (*traigo, caigo, oigo*).